# ST_DWithin taking an unreasonable time with geographical spatial indexing

Tags: postgis, spatial-index

Here are the relevant CTE's from my query:

```
campaign_ping as (
select * from campaign_pings cp 
left join campaign_pings_validity cpv on cp."ID" = cpv."pingID" 
where cpv."isValid" = true
and cp.imei in (select * from imeis)) 

,

clusters_with_coverage AS (

    -- Select the cluster_id, convex_hull geometry, and calculate coverage

    SELECT
    c.uc_name,
    c.cluster_id,
    c.convex_hull
FROM
    bfp_clusters c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM campaign_ping cp
        WHERE ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull::geography, cp."geoJson"::geography, 20)
    )
)
```

This has been running for over 900 seconds now.

Please note, the bfp_clusters table has 8399 records, and the campaign_ping CTE has 311938 records.

Further, please note that spatial indexes are implemented on the two tables as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_953f5825000b2b7d6583b3bd987" ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("ID")
CREATE INDEX bfp_clusters_conv_hull ON public.bfp_clusters USING gist (((convex_hull)::geography))
CREATE INDEX cp_date_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree ("generatedAt")
CREATE INDEX "cp_geoJson_idx" ON public.campaign_pings USING gist ("geoJson")
CREATE INDEX cp_imei_idx ON public.campaign_pings USING btree (imei)
CREATE INDEX gist_geog_cp_geojson ON public.campaign_pings USING gist (geography("geoJson"))
```

Here is the output of EXPLAIN:

```
Aggregate  (cost=350799970.50..350799970.51 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=321.86..350799949.52 rows=8391 width=0)
        Join Filter: st_dwithin((c.convex_hull)::geography, (cp."geoJson")::geography, '20'::double precision, true)
        ->  Seq Scan on bfp_clusters c  (cost=0.00..457.99 rows=8399 width=300)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=321.86..19696.85 rows=1671 width=32)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=321.86..19688.50 rows=1671 width=32)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=321.29..8070.04 rows=2752 width=48)
                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=272.98..272.99 rows=1 width=16)
                                Group Key: (a."IMEI")::text
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=32.53..272.98 rows=1 width=16)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=32.25..269.64 rows=1 width=7)
                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=27.40..168.70 rows=1 width=16)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on area_type at2  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=16)
                                                        Filter: ((name)::text = 'Uc'::text)
                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on area a2  (cost=27.40..167.64 rows=1 width=32)
                                                        Recheck Cond: ("areaTypeID" = at2."ID")
                                                        Filter: ((name)::text = 'MALANA'::text)
                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_ae316350b68c2f5f18f0052f59"  (cost=0.00..27.40 rows=2016 width=0)
                                                              Index Cond: ("areaTypeID" = at2."ID")
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_area_assets caa  (cost=4.84..100.21 rows=72 width=23)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ("campaignScopeAreaID" = a2."ID")
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_baa27c8ade8e5231dd1f31609a"  (cost=0.00..4.83 rows=72 width=0)
                                                        Index Cond: ("campaignScopeAreaID" = a2."ID")
                                      ->  Index Scan using "PK_2da8ab8bece3ae8da02e5bf1c93" on assets a  (cost=0.29..3.34 rows=1 width=23)
                                            Index Cond: (("ID")::text = (caa."assetID")::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_pings cp  (cost=48.31..7749.13 rows=4792 width=63)
                                Recheck Cond: ((imei)::text = (a."IMEI")::text)
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cp_imei_idx  (cost=0.00..47.11 rows=4792 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: ((imei)::text = (a."IMEI")::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using "PK_67c42d3c76ee09d085cf687e60c" on campaign_pings_validity cpv  (cost=0.56..4.22 rows=1 width=16)
                          Index Cond: ("pingID" = cp."ID")
                          Filter: "isValid"
JIT:
  Functions: 33
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Comment: using `explain (buffers, analyze)` instead of only `explain` would show the timings

Comment: we see that the CTE is materialized, i.e its content is retrieved once only, so any index on its underlying tables won't be used (the spatial index in this case!). You can try to add the `not materialized` [directive](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257014/are-there-side-effects-to-postgres-12s-not-materialized-directive) or to simply remove/embed it inside the `where exists` clause

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to save its content in a temp table having the spatial index

Comment: @JGH I embedded it inside the where not exists clause, but no joy. Still taking upwards of 5 minutes.